# MySQL select first occurrence group by event

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of musical events from different singers, each singer has different concerts, i need to extract the 'next event' in such a way that for every singer I choose the next occurrence and only the next one

for example for this table

```
id | singerId | occurrence
1  |     1    | 2017-01-01
2  |     1    | 2017-02-01
3  |     2    | 2017-03-01
4  |     2    | 2017-04-01
```

result should be

```
id | singerId | occurrence
1  |     1    | 2017-01-01
3  |     2    | 2017-03-01
```

I've tried with

```
select distinct * from table 
where occurrence > '2016-12-12 22:10:00' 
group by singerId 
order by occurrence
```

but somehow I am not getting the next occurrence in all cases, sometimes an occurrence is one in the middle, not the next one

'next' is the closest to 2016-12-12 22:10:00 greater than it

What is wrong in my query?

Comment: How do you defined "next"? 2017-01-01 is in the past.

Comment: next occurrence with respect to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you are saying, try this. Very vague on "next occurrence" definition.

```
select id, singerId, Min(Occurrence) Occurrence
from table 
where occurrence > '2016-12-12 22:10:00' 
group by id, singerId 
order by occurrence
```